# apt-get update returns error 404 because of iceweasel

Tags: apt, kali-linux, iceweasel, rvm

Since Debian uses firefox instead of iceweasel, apt-get update returns 404 errors with this URL:

```
http://mozilla.debian.net/dists/wheezy-backports/iceweasel-release/binary-amd64/Packages
```

I had installed firefox-esr in order to migrate to firefox and I have no problem, I can use Firefox.

I use rvm and when I try to install ruby with it, it stop the installation because apt-get update returns a error 404. [Read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650992/ruby-rvm-apt-get-update-error)

I use Kali Linux and my sources.list is clean:

```
#kali 2.0
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-free
```

How to delete these 404 errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find and remove line saying:

```
deb http://mozilla.debian.net/...
```

If it is not in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then it is somewhere else, most probably `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

You can also use `fgrep -r mozilla.debian.net /etc` to find it.

Note that this file might be part of some old debian package (find out which with `dpkg -S /etc/apt/sources.list.d/blahblah.conf`) - in that case, it is probably best to `dpkg --purge` that old iceweasel package.

Comment: In order to solve my problem, I delete this file that contain: `deb http://mozilla.debian.net/ wheezy-backports iceweasel-release`

The location of this file is /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla-debian.list.